# Jest with ES6 and Typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm currently trying to test my Express apis with Supertest and Jest however I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to find the answer to.

This is my api.

```
router.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const products: ProductType[] = await MongooseModel.find({});
  res.send(products);
});
```

This is my test suite.

```
import request from 'supertest';
import products from './products';

describe('GET /', () => {
  it('responds with status 200', async () => {
    const response = await request(products).get('/');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

And this is my babel.config.js

```
export const presets = [
  ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  +'@babel/preset-typescript',
  +'@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
];
```

When I try to run the tests, I get this response:

```
.presets[1] must be a string, object, function
```

Could anyone please help me figure this headache out?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `+` sign to join them?

Comment: `+'@babel/preset-typescript'` is `NaN`, which indeed isn't a valid preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the meaningless `+` in your preset. `+'@babel/preset-typescript'` is a number with its value `NaN`, which is neither a string, an object nor a function. `'@babel/preset-typescript'` (and the following one) may be what you want.

[image: with and without the '+']

Answer (score 2):

Word to the wise:

The `+` is the result of following the [Jest documentation for Typescript support](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started). If you press their button to copy the `babel.config.js` snippet they have, it grabs their formatting rules as well, including the `+` (which they are using to illustrate the addition of the line `"@babel/preset-typescript"` on top of the boilerplate Babel configuration).